# Ajax POST request does not work

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, rest, spring-mvc

I have read lot of answers to this question in this forum and others and code looks ok but problem still persists. When I do POST request,I get 400 error code(bad request). But When I call same resource from POSTMAN client, I get response back successfully. Can anyone please look into my code and see what am I doing wrong.

```
public class Country{

    int id;
    String countryName; 

    @JsonCreator
    public Country(@JsonProperty("id")int id, @JsonProperty("countryName")String countryName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }
    ....setter/getters
    }
```

REST Controller File

```
 @RestController
    public class CountryController {
        static List<Country> listOfCountries = new ArrayList<Country>();
        static{
            createCountryList();
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/countries", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
        public List<Country> getCountries()
        {
            return listOfCountries;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/addCountry", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
        public List<Country> addCountry(@RequestBody Country country)
        {System.out.println("addcountry called"+country);
            listOfCountries.add(country);
            return listOfCountries;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/country/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
        public Country getCountryById(@PathVariable int id)
        {

            for (Country country: listOfCountries) {
                if(country.getId()==id)
                    return country;
            }

            return null;
        }

    // Utiliy method to create country list.
        public static List<Country> createCountryList()
        {
            Country indiaCountry=new Country(1, "India");
            Country chinaCountry=new Country(4, "China");
            Country nepalCountry=new Country(3, "Nepal");
            Country bhutanCountry=new Country(2, "Bhutan");

            listOfCountries.add(indiaCountry);
            listOfCountries.add(chinaCountry);
            listOfCountries.add(nepalCountry);
            listOfCountries.add(bhutanCountry);
            return listOfCountries;
        }
    }
```

JS File Content

```
 $(function() {
        var $ords = $('#orders');
        var $cid = $('#cid');
        var $name = $('#name');

        function displayOrder(country){
            $ords.append('<li>Id :' + country.id + ',name : '+ country.countryName + '</li>');
        }
        $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url : 'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample/countries',

                    success : function(data) {
                        // data = JSON.parse(data);
                        $.each(data, function(i, country) {
                            displayOrder(country);
                        });
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        alert("error loading data");
                    }
                });
        $("#add").on("click", function(){
            var country= {
                    id:$cid.val(),
                    countryName:$name.val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestfulWebServicesWithJSONExample/addCountry',
                data:country,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success : function(newData) {
                    // data = JSON.parse(data);
                    $.each(newData, function(i, country) {
                        displayOrder(country);
                    });
                },
                error : function() {
                    alert("error loading data");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

HTML Page relevant section

```
<body>
    <h2>Country Names</h2>
    <ul id="orders">
    </ul>
    <p>Id: <input type="text" id="cid"></p>
    <p>Name: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
    <button id="add">Add</button>
</body>
```

Comment: If page is on different port you need to implement CORS in server . look in browser dev tools console would see CORS error

Comment: No, page is running on 8080 and service controller also running on same port.

Comment: Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to see exactly what is sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you aren't sending JSON. Setting contentType does not automatically convert data to json you need to serialize it yourself

Change:

```
data:country,
```

To

```
data:JSON.stringify(country),
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit of your code looks wrong to me.

```
var country = {
                id:$cid.val(),
                countryName:$name.val()
              };
```

I would write it something like this:

```
var id = $cid.val(),
    countryName = $name.val();

var country = {
    "id":id,
    "countryName":countryName
}
```

The use of the double quotes around `id` and `countryName` are important in a post request.

Comment: Quotes are not important in object keys unless special characters are used in the name. Creating variables first for values will have no impact either. The object itself gets serialized before being sent

Comment: Thanks for reply. This code is from codeAcademy tutorial. Anyways, I made changes you suggested but still it showing same error.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request.